# Kernel randomly maps storage device to different device file

Tags: mount, linux-kernel, devices

So this is kind of strange. I was trying to put a screenshot into my `Videos/` directory, and while trying to `cd` where I wanted to go, I was getting I/O errors. For context, I have a storage drive mounted to `Videos/`, and my uptime at the time of this incident was:

```
$ uptime
 07:26:36 up 88 days, 14:03,  3 users,  load average: 1.21, 1.18, 1.24
```

My first assumption was that the drive went bad, so I used `mount` to figure out which device file was mapped to the drive so I could unmount and remount it to see if that would temporarily solve the problem. But the system told me that no such device exists. So I `ls /dev | grep sd` and to my surprise, `/dev/sdb*` had indeed disappeared.

I had a hunch and tried mounting the others. Namely, `sdc1` and `sdd1`; sure enough, the latter had my `Videos/` directory and it seems to be working without issues.

Somehow, the partition migrated from `sdb1` to `sdd1` without any input from me.

Why would the kernel do that? Does this indicate a problem with the drive? Kernel bug? Kernel *feature*? Does Linux tend to remap drives when a hardware fault occurs?

Comment: What does `dmesg` say?

Comment: Here's a small excerpt from the end of `dmesg | grep sdb`: https://pastebin.com/raw/HQAEkW2U

Comment: Man, this thread is dead. What's going on?

Comment: Nothing, *man*. I don't answer for your question. What are the results of research you did to solve your problem?

Comment: @arkadiusz it's not an active problem for me, actually. Just curious as to why a storage device would get mapped to another /dev/sd* file when no interruption has seemingly occurred. As for what I've tried, I googled around but didn't find anything. In terms of IT issues, I seem to always get the weird ones. Like cueball from xkcd.